# Scroll after view becomes visible

Tags: android-studio, visibility, android-scrollview, visible

I am trying to scroll to the bottom of my scrollView after a view becomes visible with button click. The problem is the scrollTo function is applied before the view is actually visible. I know this because when the button is pressed twice, it scrolls to the bottom on the second click.
So, is there a way to scroll after the view becomes visible?

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    constraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, constraintLayout.getBottom());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use a listener.

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener viewVisibilityChanged = new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        if (my_view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(0, scroll_view.getHeight());
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

You can add it to your view this way :

```
my_view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(viewVisibilityChanged);
```

Comment: I didn't actual check to see if it works for my case, but it seems like it would. And this answer is better than mine because it ensures the view is visible, not just guessing it is after a delay.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    constraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(() -> {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, constraintLayout.getBottom());
    }, 100);
}
```

I just figured out this works, but I was hoping to not use a delay.

Comment: I will accept a different answer as correct if someone comes up with one without using a delay.